# Flutter - 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true. error in the form widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Flutter - 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true. error .I am trying to edit the products in which i want a details of product in the Form that i have used in Add products.but the problem is with imageUrl because  it has a textEditing controller . I tried this way but it didnt work for me

```
@override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        if (_isinit) {
          final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
          if (productId != null) {
            _editedproduct =
                Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).FindByID(productId);
            _imageUrlController.text = _editedproduct.imageUrl;           //error
            _initValues = {
              'title': _editedproduct.title,
              'description': _editedproduct.description,
              'Price': _editedproduct.price.toString(),
              
              'imageUrl': '',                              //error
            };
          }
        }
        _isinit = false;
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }
```

[image]

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/Providers/Product.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/Providers/Products.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-products';
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedproduct =
      Product(id: '', title: '', description: '', price: 0, imageUrl: '');
  var _isinit = true;

  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isinit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedproduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).FindByID(productId);
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedproduct.imageUrl;           //error
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedproduct.title,
          'description': _editedproduct.description,
          'Price': _editedproduct.price.toString(),
          
          'imageUrl': '',                              //error
        };
      }
    }
    _isinit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedproduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProducts(_editedproduct.id, _editedproduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProducts(_editedproduct);
    }

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: _saveForm,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a value.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: value as String,
                      price: _editedproduct.price,
                      description: _editedproduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Price',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a  price ';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please Enter a Valid Number';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Please Enter the number greather no than zero';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: _editedproduct.title,
                      price: double.parse(value!),
                      description: _editedproduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                ),
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                maxLines: 3,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a  description ';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: _editedproduct.title,
                      price: _editedproduct.price,
                      description: value as String,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? Text('Enter a URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(
                              _imageUrlController.text,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URl'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      initialValue: _initValues['imageUrl'],    //error
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,        //error
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a  URL ';
                        }
                        if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                            !value.startsWith('https')) {
                          return 'Please Enter a valid URL';
                        }
                        if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid image URL';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedproduct = Product(
                            title: _editedproduct.title,
                            price: _editedproduct.price,
                            description: _editedproduct.description,
                            imageUrl: value as String,
                            id: _editedproduct.id,
                            isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ITs not allowed to Set the controller and the Initial value. You can Set the initil value with the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for the error is because you set a controller and an initial value. You have to set only one of these properties. Either an initial value or a controller. Do this in all occurences

For example Change this

```
 TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URl'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                  initialValue: _initValues['imageUrl'],    //error
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  controller: _imageUrlController,        //error
                  focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a  URL ';
                    }
                    if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                        !value.startsWith('https')) {
                      return 'Please Enter a valid URL';
                    }
                    if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                        !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                        !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid image URL';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    _saveForm();
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedproduct = Product(
                        title: _editedproduct.title,
                        price: _editedproduct.price,
                        description: _editedproduct.description,
                        imageUrl: value as String,
                        id: _editedproduct.id,
                        isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                  },
                ),
```

to the following ommitting the initial value

```
 TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URl'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  controller: _imageUrlController,        //error
                  focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a  URL ';
                    }
                    if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                        !value.startsWith('https')) {
                      return 'Please Enter a valid URL';
                    }
                    if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                        !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                        !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid image URL';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    _saveForm();
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedproduct = Product(
                        title: _editedproduct.title,
                        price: _editedproduct.price,
                        description: _editedproduct.description,
                        imageUrl: value as String,
                        id: _editedproduct.id,
                        isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                  },
                ),
```

I believe this approach should work

Comment: thanks it's work for me